# Businesshours.nextStartDate is returning value which is on a holiday

Tags: businesshours

In our org, I have set-up business hours as 08:00-16:00 and timezone is GMT +2.
Saturdays and Sundays are blank which means they are holidays.
[image]

I then went in and set-up Holidays and have put the 24th, 25th and 26th of December as full day recurring holidays.
[image]

Now when I call the following method:

```
public static date verifySelectedDate (date userSelectedValue){
    BusinessHours bh = [SELECT Id FROM BusinessHours WHERE IsDefault=true];
    DateTime dt = datetime.newInstance(userSelectedValue, Time.newInstance(12,59,59,59));
    DateTime nextStart = BusinessHours.nextStartDate(bh.Id,dt);
      System.debug('the value for datetime nextstart is '+nextStart);
    date deliveryDate=nextStart.date();
    return deliveryDate;
}
```

The issue is that when the userSelectedValue is "2018-12-22" (Saturday) the BusinessHours.nextStartDate method returns:

> USER_DEBUG [59]|DEBUG|the value for datetime nextstart is 2018-12-24 06:00:00

This is incorrect as this is configured as a holiday in the system and should be skipped over. The value returned should be 2018-12-27 06:00:00.

Any ideas why the method is not taking holidays into consideration?

Answer (score 2):

Alright, so found out the reason why this was happening.
I had forgotten to associate the Holidays with the business hours. I had entered the holidays in the system (System>>Company Information>>Holidays), but had not associated them to my default business hours #facepalm.
Had to go into my business hours and then add the holidays using the related list of Holidays on the business hours page.